# Prevent overwriting some folders/files when deployong Java/JEE .war in jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss

I have a war file containing multiple .jrxml files in a folder inside WEB-INF, what i do is unzip the war , update manually the content of those .jrxml files  , and then zip the war again before deploying it into jboss.
my question is, can i somehow prevent jboss from deleting those updated files if i deploy ( without zipping and manually putting the files in the war and zipping again) a new .war ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what your are trying to accomplish. How are you deploying your war file? Are you talking about a redeployment of the war? What do you mean "prevent jboss from deleting files"? Do you mean temporary files JBoss is creating upon deployment?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, yes im talking about those files, i want to prevent jboss from overwriting some folders in those files

Comment: This must not be done. These are internal, temporary files JBoss is creating upon deployment state. Please change your question and describe what you originally wanted to achieve by doing so.